# Best way to emit changes between components and don't pass information

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I listen to change in Component A, that something changing in Component B but I could not pass any information. Somthing like void only know that any change has occured.
I create service and BehaviourSubcject. That components don't have any relationts child->parent, parent->child

```
somethingChangeInComponent = new BehaviorSubject('');
```

In component B

```
handleOnClick() {
      this.service.somethingChangeInComponent.next('sss');
}
```

In component A in Constructor

```
this.service.somethingChangeInComponent.subscribe(res => .... );
```

It's work fine but some string is redundant and unnecessary.
What is the best way to listen for changes without passing any parameters ?

Comment: If component A and B have a parent child relationship ... then you could have an Input/Ouput of an eventEmitter that you notify the other that something changed.   But if they are unrelated ... the service is your best option.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the `BehaviourSubject` then a simple `Subject` will suffice

```
change = new Subject();
change.next();
```